# how to save current page to file in 'less'?

Tags: files, less

So in Linux, less is used to read files page by page for better readability. I was wondering if you can do something like

```
less file.txt > output.txt
```

to get one page worth of file.txt and output/write it to output.txt.

(Asking on behalf of yyin stackoverflow OP)

Answer (score 1):

there's a sequence of `less` commands that can do what you want with less:

1) type `|` , the prompt will change to `|mark:`

2) type `.` ( a dot) , the prompt will change to `!`

3) type `tee output.txt` to write the current page to that file.

What a page is on console?
From the ***xterm*** man page:

*page

 Select all visible lines, i.e., the page.*

If the console is resized, the number of lines will change :-p

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way of doing somewhat like this (over the top-of-my-head) could be:

```
$ script someFile // to make a typescript of the terminal session
$ less file.txt
<Quit less(1) now>
$ exit // this exits the script(1)
```

Check out the content of "someFile" file now as it should give some idea as to what you need, although cleaning will be required unless you can improve (dig a bit deeper).